# Cannot access seeds in my factories when running Rails unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factories

I have factories that include some setup data.  For example:

```
Factory.define :event do |event|
  event.name  { Factory.next(:email) }
  event.blurb "Test event blurb"
  event.association(:owner, :factory => :user)
  event.countries Country.all
end
```

Country.all just assigns all countries from a lookup table to that particular event.  I include all the countries by loading seeds before I run my tests with this line in my test helper:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"
```

This works great when running individual unit tests:

```
ruby test/unit/event_test.rb
```

However Country.all returns nothing when I run the test using:

```
rake test:units
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require seeds in the test_helper, it's loaded once. After each test run database is wiped out, including seeded data. In order to make seeds load every time, add something like this to your test_helper's `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class definition.

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # this line:
  setup { load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds" }
end
```

Comment: I should also note that it was necessary to put attributes that access the database in a block.  event.countries Country.all becomes event.countries { Country.all }

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source code for the `rake` gem. It looks like you'll have to load your `seeds.rb` file manually in each test file, or better yet, from `test_helper.rb`.

Comment: I was doing it from my test_helper.rb already but as hakunin pointed out, had to be done in each file and also the attributes accessing the data in a factory needed to be put in blocks